# A Tab Exception Message

Tags: android

06-14 00:21:30.398: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'

what it means? I've already given the id for tabhost.And I can see the id in R.java.

### Here is the .xml:

```
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are going to use `TabActivity`, you need to use `@android:id/tabhost` as the `android:id` value of your `TabHost`.

Comment: @Kooper: Then you had a different error message. The message you have in your question is solved by the answer that I have given. Here is some sample code: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Comment: may want to make sure you are not accidentally extending TabActivity which can cause that error message as well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the line "android:id="@+id/tabhost". The "@+" character means you are directing android to look in your local R file. This is fine in most cases if you have defined an id there, but not when you are looking for a built in id from the OS. The rule with extending TabActivity is you have to give the TabHost the "magic" android tabhost id. This means you need a line like "android:id=@android:id/tabhost" (note the lack of the "@+").

Comment: Just had this problem- Using this solution (which I was already trying) paired with Project->Clean seems to do the trick. Also, not sure what the comment on the other answer is about, but I am extending TabActivity- as far as I know this is required.

Answer (score 1):

you should remove the statement

```
tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(***********);
```

and add

```
tabHost = getTabHost();
```